# Squid Proxy - Hiding the proxy

Tags: linux, squid

I have setup squid proxy on an ubuntu server with DB authentication. However, whilst connected to the proxy, if I visit http://www.whatismyip.com/ it still shows my ACTUAL ip address. How can I configure Squid to hide my IP and to hide the fact it's using squid.

Comment: Why do you want/need to hide it?

Comment: In order to be able to access IP restricted services without reealing the fact I'm using a proxy, like this: http://www.kickassproxy.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Squid has `Forwarded-For` turned on. For more info on what [`X-Forwarded-For`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) is, have a gander at the Wikipedia article.

In your situation, you'll want to edit your Squid configuration file to include this line: `forwarded_for off` and then restart `/etc/init.d/squid restart` (assuming a RPM-based distro).

Comment: In addition, you have to check `'Via'` option (should be 'off'.)

Comment: This hides the IP address. Which is half the problem so thanks. But http://www.whatismyip.com/ is still able to detect that I'm using a proxy..

Comment: The `via` option did it (in comination with `forwarded_for`)!

Answer (score 0):

I use this site to verify the proxy is properly hidden: http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test

It's not enough to set `forwarded_for off`!
It will still send `X-Forwarded-For: unknown`, so others will know you use some kind of proxy (although your IP is hidden).

Add those 2 lines to your `squid.conf` file:

```
forwarded_for delete
via off
```

Then restart squid with `service squid3 restart` command, and you're done!

More information:

- http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/forwarded_for/
- http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/via/